# I can't load remix neither in the browser nor on my local computer!

Tags: solidity, remix, error, solidity-0.8.x

I get this error: Worker error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The URL 'undefined/soljson-v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.js' is invalid.
Zoom outZoom in
And for some reason, remix won't load at all on my local conputer!

Answer (score 0):

Thats wierd.
You should report it to the community, they'll definitely gonna help you IA

Remix Communities https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/community.html